# How do I reverse this firmware? 8-bit handheld console

Tags: firmware, embedded, decompile, rom

[image]

I recently bought this chinese console that supposedly has 328 8-bit games. I want to understand the code and how it works to hack it and maybe load other ROMs. It has a chip covered in black epoxy resin that may be the microcontroller, and right next to it there's a flash memory, specifically the Winbond branded W25Q64 64Mbit (8 Mbyte) memory. Since I have an EEPROM/Flash reader I extracted the data from it. This is the complete .bin file: https://www.4shared.com/s/fYlAk9898gm

[image: dinax.bin file in HxD]

I dont know what kind of processing I need to do to make readable-like code. The binary contains recognizable data like the index of the games, but is not much more

Comment: AFAIK, there is no tool which willl automatically identify the processor typw from a binary file.

Comment: @fpmurphy1 https://github.com/airbus-seclab/cpu_rec

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky.  Very interesting!  Thanks.

Comment: One of the first steps I take when reversing a firmware/binary dump is to analyse the file through a tool like [binwalk](https://github.com/ReFirmLabs/binwalk).

Comment: Hi. 

Looks like flash contain mostly data - games index, game data, possibly some code related to specific games. 

Can you identify serial output on PCB itself? Maybe there are some other ports/sockets that looks familiar and may be used to solder in/connect the debug/usb/serial to observe SoC on chip under epoxy?

Comment: Could you upload the file to a civilized upload service, like mega, mediafire or google drive? I don't know why 4shared wants me to create an account, and I don't know whether I want to know...